How do I add logic to a QWeb report?
I want to create a somewhat sophisticated report with invoices, but I have never worked with QWeb.
Is there any way to implement python logic to the xml?
Such as comparing dates, as in this example.
<odoo>
  <template id="report_cierre_de_caja_id">
    <t t-call="web.basic_layout">
      <div class="page">
        <h2>Reporte de Cierre de Caja</h2>
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Número de Factura</th>
              <th>Monto Total</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="factura">
              <t t-if="factura.invoice_date == Date.today()">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <t t-esc="factura.name" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <t t-esc="factura.amount_total" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </t>
            </t>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </t>
  </template>
</odoo>


You cannot use Date.today() directly in a QWeb template like that. Instead, you need to make use of the available Python methods and fields directly within your models.

@StevenWillers Could you help me with an example?
